# How to run application befoure running tests (gradle/kotlin/springboot)

Tags: gradle, cucumber, circleci

I am currently attempting to prepare an app for cloudfoundery. This particular CF instance only supports CircleCI. My app has a bunch of unit tests and a few cucumber tests. I am trying to get these to pass befoure using CircleCI to cf push.

Everytime CircleCI runs it fails on the "gradle test" command. Looking at the log the unit tests pass and the cucumber tests fail. **I blieve this is due to the fact that the cucumber tests require the app to be running.**

Here is an example stack trace of a cucumber test:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1220)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:984)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:730)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:706)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:299)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:288)
    at cucumber.runtime.kotlin.test.StepDefinitions.getPage(StepDefinitions.kt:29)
    at ✽.I am on the main page(features/SearchWithFilters.feature:8)
```

Here is my current config.yml:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      # specify the version you desire here
      - image: circleci/openjdk:8-jdk

    working_directory: ~/repo

    environment:
      # Customize the JVM maximum heap limit
      JVM_OPTS: -Xmx3200m
      TERM: dumb

    steps:
      - checkout

      # Download and cache dependencies
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
          - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}
          # fallback to using the latest cache if no exact match is found
          - v1-dependencies-

      - run: gradle dependencies

      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - ~/.gradle
          key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}

      - run: gradle clean assemble jar
      - run: java -jar build/libs/definitions-catalogue-1.0.jar &

      # run tests
      - run: gradle test
```

Comment: I am assuming you're trying to start the app with this line ` - run: java -jar build/libs/definitions-catalogue-1.0.jar &` but it may not be starting in time since the next step runs immediatelt.  You can use something like `curl` which has built-in timeout and retry to effectively block until the app is readily.

More ideally your gradle test command should be both starting and waiting for the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used dockerize to get around this issue.

There are 3 steps involved.

1. Run the application in the background
2. Use dockerize to wait for a port to open (this works as the application listens on a cretin port.
3. Run tests.

code to do this is as follows:

```
      - run: java -jar definitions-catalogue-1.0.jar &

      - run:
          name: install dockerize
          command: wget https://github.com/jwilder/dockerize/releases/download/$DOCKERIZE_VERSION/dockerize-linux-amd64-$DOCKERIZE_VERSION.tar.gz && sudo tar -C /usr/local/bin -xzvf dockerize-linux-amd64-$DOCKERIZE_VERSION.tar.gz && rm dockerize-linux-amd64-$DOCKERIZE_VERSION.tar.gz
          environment:
            DOCKERIZE_VERSION: v0.3.0
      - run:
          name: Run the application
          background: true
          command: gradle run
      - run:
          name: Wait for web service
          command: dockerize -wait http://localhost:5002/definitions -timeout 1m

      # run tests!
      - run: gradle featureTest
```